# How to output extension only from splitExt?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this old `batch` code for taking files (that are not in use) in a directory root, and putting them in directories (using filename for dir name):

```
for %%s in (*.*) do if not "%%~xs"==".!qB" if not "%%~xs"==".parts" (
    md "%%~ns" & move "%%s" "%%~ns\"
    if exist "%%s" rd "%%~ns"
)
```

this would take a `d:\currentdir\filename.ext` file and use filename to nest it into `d:\currentdir\filename\filename.ext`, unless the file extension is a known temp file like `.!qB` or `.parts`.

I am trying to rewrite this into python..

```
rootfiles = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in rootfiles:
    print(os.path.splitext(f))
```

I'm  stuck at `splitExt`, how do I get only the extension variable so I can exclude the known temp extensions mentioned? I don't get it from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

os.path.splitext returns a tuple.  You can select either value using the standard brackets like you would with a list.

```
rootfiles = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in rootfiles:
    print(os.path.splitext(f)[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
rootfiles = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f) and not f.endswith(".!qB") and not f.endswith(".parts")]
```